# How can I display an transparent button over an selection of an CollectionView Cell Image View in swift IOS Example?

Tags: ios

How can I display an another image on selection of an Collection View Cell ImageView in an swift language of IOS example.

Comment: Hope this could help. https://hackernoon.com/uicollectionviewcell-selection-made-easy-41dae148379d

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you,

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                         didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // here you know which item is selected by accessing indexPath.item property, for example: and then reload only selected cell

}
```

Thanks